# creating weak_pointer from a shared_pointer and reusing a basic pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Why is `wp5` not pointing to an `Integer` whose value is `50`?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

class Integer {
private:
    int number;
public:
    Integer(int number) : number(number) {}

    int get() { return number; }

};

int main() {

    Integer i1(10);
    Integer i2(20);
    i1 = i2;
    std::cout << "i1 = " << i1.get() << std::endl;
    Integer* i3 = new Integer(30);
    std::shared_ptr<Integer> sp3 = std::make_shared<Integer>(i1);
    std::shared_ptr<Integer> sp4 = std::shared_ptr<Integer>(new Integer(40));
    std::weak_ptr<Integer> wp5 = std::shared_ptr<Integer>(new Integer(50));
    std::weak_ptr<Integer> wp6 = sp4;



    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to create a `shared_pointer<Integer>` or a `weak_pointer<Integer>` that use `*i3` as a basic pointer to the `Integer(30)`?

Comment: Because you initialized it from a temporary object that gets immediately destroyed. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: You can't. That's not how weak pointers work. Unless you can point a finger to somewhere in your code where you have a shared pointer variable referencing a given object, it is logically impossible for a weak pointer to the same object to exist at the same time. Where is the shared ptr which holds a strong reference to your "Integer(30)", here?